# Get App Engine logs with the help of remote_api

Tags: python, google-app-engine, logging, remote-access

I am trying to get my appengine application logs from remote. I am using remote_api, I tried with appcfg but I discarded it because it has a limit on the download/buffer so I can't download all the logs.

Now I am using the logservice, but if I use it in my code it doesn't return anything. Here is my code:

```
import time


import urllib2

from google.appengine.ext.remote_api import remote_api_stub
from google.appengine.api.logservice import logservice

import getpass
import base64
import os
from appcfg import *
import getpass
import subprocess

os.environ['HTTP_X_APPENGINE_TASKRETRYCOUNT']='1'
os.environ["SERVER_SOFTWARE"] = "Developement"
os.environ['HTTP_HOST'] = 'unitTest'
os.environ['CURRENT_MODULE_ID']='default'
os.environ['CURRENT_VERSION_ID']='1.0'


email_address = "********"
application_url = "myappid.appspot.com"
def aut():
    app_name = "myappid.appspot.com"
    f = lambda : ("*EMAIL*", "*PASSWORD*")
    remote_api_stub.ConfigureRemoteApi(None, '/_ah/remote_api', auth_func,app_name)
    print("successfully authenticated")

    fetch_logs()


def fetch_logs():
    end_time = time.time()
    print ("starting")
    for req_log in logservice.fetch(end_time = end_time, offset = None, minimum_log_level = logservice.LOG_LEVEL_INFO, 
            include_app_logs=True, include_incomplete=True):
    print req_log.ip


def auth_func():
   global email_address
   return (email_address, getpass.getpass('Password:'))




aut()
```

It successfully connects to my app and he make the logservice.fetch(), but it returns an empty object... why?

Comment: Why not to use appcfg.py to download them?

Comment: "I tried with appcfg but I discarded it because it has a limit on the download/buffer so I can't download all the logs."

Comment: Then you can try mapreduce with LogInputReader and FileWriterOutput. Then you can easy download results from Cloud Storage. Remote API is not great for downloading big data..